# Laravel price validation only accept positive number and not only 0

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to validate a "price" field in Laravel.

The price should only contain numbers without (.) or (,) and cant start with 0 as well.

Eg

**2500 // Pass**

**02500 // Fails**

**12.12 // Fails**

**12,12 / Fails**

The rule I have now looks like this:

```
'price' => 'required|integer|not_in:0',
```

It seems to work with the example above, however I dont understand it. Why does not `integer` allow something like **0123** with a starting zero. I just want to make sure that my rule works as excpected and that I dont miss something

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you're not sure about the rule "integer", you can use the regex expression validation as following :

```
'price' => 'required|regex:^[1-9][0-9]+|not_in:0',
```

I had some issue same way as you, and since then i always used the regex validation for this kind of requirements. Furthermore it allow you to take back the same regex if you want to make a front validation with js.

Here is the laravel function allowing to validate integers :

```
public function validateInteger($attribute, $value)
{
    return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false;
}
```

SO it's PHP itself that is concerned by this behavior. PHP tells us this thing about FILTER_VALIDATE_INT :

> Validates value as integer, optionally from the specified range, and
>   converts to int on success.

No other informations are set by PHP about the "0" value, but it's known that this function doesn't consider numbers starting by "0".

Comment: Yea I can easyly use a regex and added it too my frontend validation, but I want to understand Why laravels rule **integer** does not allow leading zero

Comment: I used same but giving me error preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: @JagrutiMetaliya write in separate array instead of pipe

Answer (score 46):

This works for me:

```php
'price' => 'required|numeric|gt:0',
```

Comment: The cleanest solution

Comment: This is clean but what if you want to accept 0 price value

Comment: Then add gte:0.

Comment: gt:field !!! it should be a field name after gt:

Answer (score 13):

You can format the input before sending it to the validator in your `Request` class.

```
   public function formatInput()
{
  $input = array_map('trim', $this->all());

  $input['price'] = (int)($input['price']);
  $this->replace($input);
  return $this->all();
}
```

Then you can use

```
'price' => 'required|integer|min:0',
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Does not laravel do this out of the box since v5.4? I was thinking of the **\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,** middleware   https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-middleware

Comment: @user2722667 its just an example you can skip this

Answer (score 3):

Use [regex](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-regex) rule to not allow for integer with starting 0

```
'price' => 'required|integer|not_in:0|regex:^[1-9][0-9]+',
```

Comment: Yea I can easyly use a regex, but I want to understand Why laravels rule **integer** does not allow leading zero

Comment: numeric and gt:0 will be enough